# How to fire onResume() on top most fragment only, on back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, onresume

I have 2 Activity(s). Inside 1st Activity there is initially one Fragment

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, MainFragment.newInstance().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

then clicking on a button `replaces` it with another Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    DetailFragment detail = (DetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail, detail, "detail").commit();
}
```

On 2nd Fragment there is another button, clicking on it opens a New Activity.

```
Intent popUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUp.class);                      
popUp.putExtra("CarID", carID);
startActivity(popUp);
```

From PopUp Activity, pressing device back will go back to MainActivity.
Now the challenge is for the Application's business logic I need to update the ActionBar's title of previous MainActivity when user goes back.

For this I'm listening for onResume() on both MainFragment and DetailFragment. Also when user goes back from DetailFragment to MainFragment I update the ActionBar title with different text.

So I need to know when exactly user goes back from:

> 1) PopUp Activity > Detail Fragment
>
> 2) Detail Fragment > Main Fragment

Currently `onResume()` is fired on both `MainFragment` and `DetailFragment` when `PopUpActivity` is closed. On `MainFragment` I can't exactly find out whether `onResume()` is called for 1st or 2nd case.

What is the best practice to fire `onResume()` on `DetailFragment` only when user goes back from `PopUpActivity` > `DetailFragment`. In other words, how do I detect from `DetailFragment` that `PopUpActivity` is closed without firing `onResume()` on `MainFragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with `onResume()` for something like this.

I would suggest doing the following:

- Create a `Stack<String>` for titles.
- Implement `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` in your `MainActivity`.
- In your `onBackStackChanged()` implementation, check if the back stack has been pushed or popped using `FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()`.

  - If the back stack has been pushed, push the newly-displayed fragment's title to your title stack.
  - If the back stack has been popped, pop a title and set the title bar with the title at the new top of stack.
- If you set a title from a fragment that *isn't* added to the back stack, pop a title from the title stack and push the newly-displayed fragment's title, i.e. replace the title at the top of the stack.
- Invoke your `PopupActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.
- Override `onActivityResult()` in your `MainActivity` so that when `PopupActivity` returns, you set the title bar with the title at the top of stack.
- Don't forget to persist your title stack in `onSaveInstanceState()` in your `MainActivity` and restore it in `onCreate()`.

That might seem like a lot of work just for maintaining titles, but you will drive yourself crazy trying to do this with `onResume`.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            // handle back button

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

}